# Regular Expression pattern to match a html tag in LEX utility?

Tags: regex, lex

I m new to Lex.
I want to write a lex program to extract all html tags from a file.
I tried several patters to match the tags but all failed to work properly.

I tried

```
"<"[^>]*> /*The quotes because lex utility gives error that improper start of expression*/
"<"[a-z]+[/]*>
```

and many more... But when I execute a line like

```
<h1> This is a heading </h1>
```

on them, and try to print it with yytext, it simply prints complete line of code as it is instead of just printing

```
<h1></h1>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expression.

Comment: What else can be done? My problem definition is to create a lex program which extracts all html tags out of a input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer.
What I was doing was, having no action for the rest unmatched text.
I made my rule section of lex program as:

```
"<"[^>]*> { /* action for tags */ }
.|\n     ;
```

And thats that. Now it prints the desired output.